# List of Services deployed in Karaf Container

Tags: osgi, karaf

I have several Karaf-Containers in different environments, each with 50+ services deployed, and I´m looking for an easy way to compare the versions in each environment.

Is it possible to retrieve a list of all deployed services including the specific version via the jmx-Interface?

Comment: Do you really mean the services or the bundles?

Comment: You are right, i mean the version of the installed bundles.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the BundlesMBean with objectName `org.apache.karaf:type=bundle,name=root`.

The attribute `Bundles` returns Tabular data that contains among other details `Symbolic Name` and `Version`.

Simply try with jconsole. It is easy to connect to a local karaf installation.